# React-Admin is populating my <List> with same element

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, react-admin

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-lovelace-225lk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I'm trying to create a nice admin dashboard with `react-admin`.
As using `spring` in my backend and this is how am sending data to `react-admin`:

```java
@GetMapping("admin/user")
ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll()
{
   System.out.println(new Date());;

   HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Content-Range", "posts 0-"+userRepository.findAll().size() + "/" + userRepository.findAll().size());
        responseHeaders.set("Origin", "http://localhost:3001");

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
             .headers(responseHeaders)
             .body(userRepository.findAll());
}
```

*First of all this is not working and secondly, this is not even close to correct solution*.

Unfortunately, my client renders the last thing over and over again.
As you can see **below**, element with `id 129` is rendered over and over again!

[image: react-admin populating list with same element]

At the frontend, within `react.js`:

```js
// Within main/parent component
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Admin dataProvider={restProvider('http://localhost:8080/admin')}>
         <Resource name="user" list={UserList}/>
      </Admin>
    );
  }
};

// child component
const UserList = (props) => (
   <List {...props}>
      <Datagrid>
         <TextField source="userID" />
         <TextField source="username" />
         <TextField source="firstName" />
         <TextField source="middleName" />
         <TextField source="lastName" />
         <TextField source="profileImageURL" />
         <DateField source="joiningTime" />
         <EditButton basePath="/posts" />
       </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

*I think I need a method that sort of configures every controller response with a `Content-Range` header*.

Please note that my returned data works fine in `postman`:

[image: react-admin populating list with same element]

Comment: are you sure you are getting your different different users in response ????

Comment: if yes then please add your code where you are going to render it in frontend

Comment: @PrakashKarena added front-end code, yes tested with postman, working just fine...

Comment: here is a snap of postman response : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP9FW.png

Comment: Every records needs an `id` field, yours seem to miss it. The console should show a warning about it.

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto that's a warning, not error.. and main problem isn't that.. if you can solve the real problem, that would be very helpful..

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto i still can't figure it out.. can you help me in any other way/solution ??

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad, Your API response seems okay in postman, might be some issue with react code. Can you share more code related to listing of react? If you are using Content-Range for pagination, you should go with Pageable in spring boot

Comment: @PatelRomil added full react project : https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-lovelace-225lk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-sample-l692r

Each record **must have** a field named `id` which in your case represents your `userID` field.

Use **`users`** for the resource name instead of `user`.

If you cannot change that server side, you can do it in javascript.

The following sample code should work. 
Add it to `AdminPanel.js` file in your setup:

With your backend, uncomment the following lines:

`//data: json.map(record => ({"id": record.userID, ...record})),`

`//total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),`

And change the following line:

`const apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";`

to

`const apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/admin";`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource, fetchUtils } from "react-admin";
import restProvider from "ra-data-simple-rest";
import { UserList, LoginCredentialList } from "./posts";
import { stringify } from "query-string";

const apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;

const myDataProvider = {
    ...restProvider,
    getList: (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
            filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter)
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

        return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
            data: json,
            //data: json.map(record => ({"id": record.userID, ...record})),
            total: 10, //temporary hardcoded to avoid headers error.
            //total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
        }));
    }
};

class AdminPanel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <Admin dataProvider={myDataProvider}>
                  <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
                  <Resource name="loginCredential" list={LoginCredentialList} />
              </Admin>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AdminPanel;

//                  <Resource name="posts" list={UserList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate}/>
```

Comment: it gives me [map undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzzOp.png) error, so i changed `data.map` to `json.map` it solved that problem, but gave me another new error : [has of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSmds.png), you can see it is returning data correctly now : *data : Array(18)*

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't test it.
The `has` error is due to the fact that the `headers` variable is not returned inside the Promise, since `ra-data-simple-rest` tries to use header's `has` method and `headers` parameter is `undefined`.
I've corrected the example to include it.

Comment: I can't test code right now.
In which line did you get that error?

Comment: Ok, you have to pass `data` attribute, I change the example again. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206739/discussion-between-wixsl-and-maifee-ul-asad).

Comment: in my snap, you can easily see that, i'm using data... if you really actually seeing the context i'm providing ... i have even marked that, in a red box...

Comment: I've seen your snapshot.
The error you get in `idsReducer` in line 23 is because `data` attribute is not getting found.

```js
return action.payload.data.map(f...
```

Comment: Look i'm just trying to help you

Comment: This is the correct return statement, like in the example.
I don't know why is not working in your case.

```js
return {
              json: json.map(record => ({"id": record.userID, ...record})),
              headers
          };
```

Comment: actually i'm little tensed that's why i may have misbehaved, here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-sample-225lk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)  and here is [dummy json provider](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos)

Comment: if you can solve for this one, you have correct answer anyway, right ??

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad, I set a up another example that should work. Please check it out.

Comment: See answer below, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550603/10849438, might it help?

Answer (score 4):

> The never-ending challenge of consuming data from an API

Whatever is said in the answer above is true!
**Based on the asked question, how do you provide an `id` field for `<Datagrid>` to iterate over your data and render each row/element uniquely?**

> Note that the React-Admin `dataProvider` often returns a response with a json `Object {count: <Number>, results: <Array>}`. And the results array is often mapped onto the data key e.g. `data: json.results`

`Here's what helped me while I used react-admin with a python/django backend`.
I believe in most cases, regardless of the backend, it's crucial to understand how `react-admin` consumes data (in this case a `list`). Two Solutions are possible:

1. If you have control over your backend (API), just like here.
    Then kindly update/refactor your unique identifier (in this case, `userID`) to be mapped/returned as just a plain `id` field. This will make it easier for any client consuming your data using `react-admin` or `react.js` generally.
2. Ok, so you have no control over that backend (API)!
   Then you'll have to use this line `//data: json.map(record => ({"id": record.userID, ...record}))`.

Not too fast with solution two!
There lies the commonest pitfall when working with APIs.
While we fetch data, our client **initially** (the array/list, in this case `json.results`) is undefined.
So `javascript` will complain that it `cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

How do I solve such a challenge of `undefined`?

Either directly initiate your data as an `array` or instruct the `map()` to only run if your data is not undefined (by including such a check, `typeof json !== ‘undefined’`).